# Pressing Ctrl closes browser tab

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, browser, 23.04

I'm encountering abnormal behavior with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in my browser. Sometimes, when I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, it closes the browser's tab. I had this issue with Firefox, but I tried this with another browser and it showed the same behavior.
Apart from this, everything works fine and as expected.

What have I tried?

- Pressing <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key and it also closes the tab.
- Checking key binding in settings, but found no ambiguity.
- Checked with a different keyboard and it works in the same manner.

Sometimes the browsers work fine, but most of the time pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> closes the tab.

System specifications:

- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- Browsers: Firefox 114.0.2, Edge Beta 115.0.1901.157

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in GNOME and is only in Chromium-based browsers and apps. Repeatedly hitting F4 solves the issue, now ctrl no longer closes the tab and alt no longer closes the window. But the problem appears every now and then, so keep the fix in mind and never forget it. There isn't any permanent solution (not that I know of)

Comment: I partially agree with you. I'm also facing problems related to non-chromium-based applications, specifically with Firefox (less often). Apart from the temporary solution of `F4`, I totally agreed with that.

Comment: Whats the reason to this keeps happening? Its a really strange issue to me. I use latest chrom browser. Ubuntu 23.10 and wayland.

Comment: I was facing the same issue on debian 12, switching from wayland to Xorg solved the issue. Not sure why